# How to change API to Json API in Laravel 8.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

I created API in Laravel. Friend that created Mobile app says that he can connect with my data but he requires it to be in JSON format. Here comes my question. **Is there any way to change data to JSON format in Api??**

Strange is that API gets result in JSON(at least that's what is says)

[Example of data in API results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZWQF.png)

Should I change my API to JSON:API for this to work?

My database works on MySQL if that might be necessary.

My Api routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

// Events

Route::get('/events', function(){
    $date = Carbon::now();
    return Event::where('date_of_event','>=',$date)->get();
});

Route::get('/events/{id}', function($id){

    return Event::findOrFail($id);
});

// Cities

Route::get('/cities', function(){

    return City::all();
});

Route::get('/cities/{id}', function($id){

    return City::findOrFail($id);
});

// Clubs

Route::get('/clubs', function(){

    return Club::all();
});

Route::get('/clubs/{id}', function($id){

    return Club::findOrFail($id);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ->json() on the response, there are sure other ways to do it globally.

```
return response()->json($message);
```